# JSON_encode doesn't take care of special characters?

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I am having a problem where json can encode an array But then it can't properly decode it due to special characters.

I found this function on stackoverflow that tries to help:

```
function escapeJsonString($value) 
{  # list from www.json.org: (\b backspace, \f formfeed)
                $escapers = array("\\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
                $replacements = array("\\\\", "\\/", "\\\"", "\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "\\f", "\\b");
                $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
                return $result;
    }
```

But it is only a list of characters, every time I get a new special character I have to manually deal with it and add it to the character and its replacement list.

**How do I properly take care of this?**

Comment: if the string is utf-8 json_encode does correctly handle special characters, so does json_decode, usually there is no extra replacement required if u are working with valid json, post your json code please!

Comment: Have you tried with urlencode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php?

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning your json

```
$cleanJsonData = preg_replace("/[[:cntrl:]]/", "", $jsonData);
$myData = json_decode($cleanJsonData, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` excepts the input string to be utf-8 encoded.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(utf8_encode($str));
```

This should work.

Comment: Just in case people find this on google in the future, this worked.